# xml parsing and string manipulation using perl

Tags: perl

I have an `xml` file with many lines similar to :

```
<parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="MyParameter" moc="MyParameter" moi="ABC=1473,DEF=0,GHI=0,JKL=0 />
```

My requirements are :

1. If the moc and parametername are same convert the first character in the parametername to lower case.
2. Reverse the moi like below.

So the converted line should be like :

```
<parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="myParameter" moc="MyParameter" moi="JKL=0,GHI=0,DEF.dEF=0,ABC.aBC=1473 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Element) and adding a new element for a complete example (and assuming the changes are to be made on an element called `parameter`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <DATA>);
for my $node($dom->findnodes('//parameter')) {
    my $param = $node->getAttribute('parametername');
    my $moc = $node->getAttribute('moc');
    my @moi = split ",", $node->getAttribute('moi');
    $node->setAttribute('parametername', lcfirst $param) if $param eq $moc;
    $node->setAttribute('moi', join ',', reverse @moi);
}
print $dom;
__DATA__
 <root>
  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="MyParameter" moc="MyParameter" moi="ABC=1473,DEF=0,GHI=0,JKL=0"/>
  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="foo" moc="MyParameter" moi="XYZ=1473,DEF=0,GHI=0,JKL=0"/>
</root>
```

Result:

```
<root>
  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="myParameter" moc="MyParameter" moi="JKL=0,GHI=0,DEF=0,ABC=1473"/>
  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="foo" moc="MyParameter" moi="JKL=0,GHI=0,DEF=0,XYZ=1473"/>
</root>
```

Other [ways to load_xml](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#DOM-Parser) file using XML::LibXML

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.014; 

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "xml.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($filename);
say $doc;

for my $param ($doc->findnodes('//parameter')) {
    my $pname_attr = $param->getAttribute('parametername');
    my $moc_attr = $param->getAttribute('moc');

    if ($pname_attr eq $moc_attr) {
        $param->setAttribute('parametername', lcfirst $pname_attr);

        my $moi_attr = $param->getAttribute('moi');
        my @pieces = split ',', $moi_attr;
        $pieces[0] =~ s/\A([^=]+)/$1.\l$1/xms;
        $pieces[1] =~ s/\A([^=]+)/$1.\l$1/xms;

        $param->setAttribute('moi', join ',', reverse @pieces);
    }
}

say $doc;


--output:--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="ABC" moc="CBA" moi="ABC=1473,DEF=0,GHI=0,JKL=0"/>

  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="MyParameter" moc="MyParameter" moi="ABC=1473,DEF=0,GHI=0,JKL=0"/>
</root>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="ABC" moc="CBA" moi="ABC=1473,DEF=0,GHI=0,JKL=0"/>

  <parameter element="XYZ" module="XYZ" parametername="myParameter" moc="MyParameter" moi="JKL=0,GHI=0,DEF.dEF=0,ABC.aBC=1473"/>
</root>
```

If you want to change the `moi` attribute in all the `<parameter>` tags, then the code would look like this:

```
...
...
for my $param ($doc->findnodes('//parameter')) {
    my $pname_attr = $param->getAttribute('parametername');
    my $moc_attr = $param->getAttribute('moc');

    if ($pname_attr eq $moc_attr) {
        $param->setAttribute('parametername', lcfirst $pname_attr);
    }

    my $moi_attr = $param->getAttribute('moi');
    my @pieces = split ',', $moi_attr;
    $pieces[0] =~ s/\A([^=]+)/$1.\l$1/xms;
    $pieces[1] =~ s/\A([^=]+)/$1.\l$1/xms;

    $param->setAttribute('moi', join ',', reverse @pieces);
}
```

**Response to comments:**

1)

> When I run it it says >/usr/bin/perl edit_mpvl.pl Perl v5.14.0 
>   required--this is only v5.10.0,

Change the line:

```
use 5.014;
```

to:

```
use 5.010;
```

2)

> Can we write the output to a file

Sure, add this:

```
my $fname = 'modified.xml';
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";

print {$OUTFILE} $doc->toString;
close $OUTFILE;
```

Or, you can pretty print like this:

```
...
...
use XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint;
use Readonly;
...
...
Readonly my $SPACE => " ";

my $pp = XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new(
    indent_string => $SPACE x 4   #Replace 4 by the number of spaces you want the indenting to be.
);

$pp->pretty_print($doc);  #modifies $doc inplace

print {$OUTFILE} $doc->toString;
close $OUTFILE;
```

Comment: When I run it it says >/usr/bin/perl edit_mpvl.pl 
Perl v5.14.0 required--this is only v5.10.0, stopped at edit_mpvl.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at edit_mpvl.pl line 3. When I remove the line "use 5.014; " it complains >/usr/bin/perl edit_mpvl.pl
Can't locate object method "say" via package "XML::LibXML::Document" at edit_mpvl.pl line 27.

Comment: Can we write the output to a file

Comment: @user2553620, See my responses at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @user2553620, Do you always want to reverse the moi?  Or, only for those tags where the parametername and the moc are equal?